# Calculate Ratios in JS like Humble Bundle

Tags: javascript, math

Do you know the sliders that you have on humblebundle.com when selecting where you want the money to go? Well when you adjust any one ratio it will automatically adjust the rest.

So say you're paying $20 no matter what but you want to adjust your tip to HB from $2 to $5, the ratios that were on the other stuff should automatically lowered to match but I have no idea what I'm doing.

This is as close as I get mathematically:

```
var settip = 50;
var tip = 5;
var devs = 75;
var donation = 20;

tip = settip;
var newAvail = 100 - tip;
var rCalc = 100 - (devs + donation);

devs = ((devs + rCalc) * newAvail) * .01;
donation = ((donation + rCalc) * newAvail) * .01;

console.log("New Ratio Calculation: " + rCalc);
console.log("New available space: " + newAvail);
console.log(tip);
console.log(devs);
console.log(donation);
```

The console logs are just so I can try and put it together in my head where things are going wrong. The numbers are also whole numbers first: 50 instead of .5 because Javascript is not accurate and I don't want to do the fix code every time, I'd rather figure out how to make the code work first and then think about optimizing.

So if anyone could guide me on a method or where I am going wrong here, then that'd be great. Thanks.

Tip is tip to the bundle maker.
Devs is tip to the devs.
Donation is tip to the donation box.

Each number is the ratio. Settip is the new ratio, I should be able to change any one value and have it automatically change all others but I can't even figure out how to do the first part so I couldn't begin to try for the second part of making it actually functional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this problem is not as easy as it might seem if you want to cover different edge cases. Here I assume that you distribute money so you need following properties:

1. Each amount must be whole integer in cents
2. Sum of all amounts must be equal to the total sum

The simplest way to deal with it in JS is to make all calculations using whole numbers (e.g. sum in cents instead of dollars) and format them in more human-readable way on UI. Still even with this simplification it requires some non-trivial code:

```
function updateRates(rates, newValue, index) {
    var i, len = rates.length;
    var sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
        sum += rates[i];
    var oldValue = rates[index];
    var newRest = sum - newValue;
    var curRest = sum - rates[index];
    rates[index] = newValue;
    var remainders = new Array(len);
    var fraction, value, subsum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (i === index) continue;

        // special case, all other sliders were at 0 - split value equally
        if (curRest === 0) {
            fraction = 1.0 / (len - 1)
        }
        else {
            fraction = rates[i] / curRest
        }
        value = newRest * fraction;
        rates[i] = Math.floor(value); // always round down and then distribute rest according to the Largest remainder method
        subsum += rates[i];
        remainders[i] = {
            index: i,
            value: value - rates[i]
        };
    }
    // sort remainders and distribute rest (fractions) accordingly
    remainders.sort(function (a, b) {
        var av = a.value;
        var bv = b.value;
        if (av === bv)
            return 0;
        if (av < bv)
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    });
    for (i = 0; subsum < newRest; i++) {
        rates[remainders[i].index] += 1;
        subsum += 1;
    }

    return rates;
}
```

Some non-trivial tests:

```
1. updateRates([85,10,5], 82, 0) => [82, 12, 6]
2. updateRates([85,10,5], 83, 0) => [83, 11, 6]
3. updateRates([85,10,5], 84, 0) => [84, 11, 5]
4. updateRates([100,0,0], 95, 0) => [95, 2, 3]
5. updateRates([4,3,3,1], 0, 0) =>  [0, 5, 5, 1]
```

Pay attention to the example #5. If one used some naive rounding, sum will not be preserved. Effectively you need to distribute `+4` in proportion `3:3:1`. It means you should add `+12/7`, `+12/7` and `+4/7`. Since `12/7` = `1 5/7`, according to standard mathematical rules all three should be rounded up resulting in `+2, +2, +1` but we only got `+4` cents to distribute. To fix this issue the [largest remainder method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largest_remainder_method) is used to distribute fractional cents among categories. Simply speaking the idea is that we first distribute only whole number of cents (i.e. always round down), calculate how many cents are actually left and then distribute them one by one. The biggest possible drawback of this method is that some rates that started with equal values might have different values after update. On the other hand this can't be avoided as example #4 shows: you can't split 5 cents equally between two categories.

Answer (score 0):

To restate what I think you want: the three variables `tip`, `devs` and `donation` should always sum to `100`. When one variable is updated, the other two should be updated to compensate. The automatic updates should keep the same ratios to each other (for example, if `donation` is double `devs`, and tips is updated, then the updated `donation` value should still be double the `devs` value).

If I've got that right, then this should work for you:

```js
var tips = 5;
var devs = 20;
var donation = 75;

var setTips = function(newValue) {
  tips = newValue;
  var sum = devs + donation;
  var devShare = devs / sum; // the share devs gets between devs and donation
  var donationShare = 1 - devShare; // or could calculate as donation / sum
  
  devs = (100 - tips) * devShare; // the remaining times it's share ratio
  donation = (100 - tips) * donationShare; // the remaining times it's share ratio
};

// test it out
setTips(50);
console.log(tips, devs, donation);
```